# What's the error in my code?

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, circuitikz, pgfmath, syntax

i'm trying to compile this quite easy code but i keep getting errors.
my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usepackage{flowchart}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, positioning, shapes, matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\newcommand{\mysize}{3cm}
\newcommand{\connectlength}{0.6cm}

\tikzstyle{nodestyle}=[draw, minimum size=\mysize,
label={[anchor = east]25:$\text{A}$},
label={[anchor = east]-25:$\text{B}$},]

\begin{document}

    \begin{circuitikz}[]


    \node[nodestyle] (node) {node1};
    \node[vcc, above=2cm of node]       (nodevcc) {VCC};




    \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Does anybody have an idea why?

The error message:
[image]

edit1:

I wanted to test if the `circuitikz` package works for me. Therefor i just tried to randomly set a `vcc` node (see pg8 of circuitikz manual). This error keeps occuring if i try to set node of `circuitikz`.

Comment: ok i'll edit but i think i know how to achieve it. i just wanted to test how to put the `vcc` which is nodestyle of circuitikz

Comment: The vcc shape only has anchors `center` and `text` defined, whereas `above` is trying to access south.   The quick fix is to not use `above`.

Comment: this makes sense! thank you. but let's assume if have a coordinate and i want to place the vcc 2cm above it. How can i achieve this then?

Comment: \path (node.north) ++(0pt,2cm) node... or use the calc tikzlibrary.

Answer (score 1):

I threw in three different ways to replace `[above]` in the absence of a `south` anchor.  I also removed all the redundant or unused stuff from the preamble.  Document class `standalone` was just to avoid cropping the image.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}% not needed with an ASCII editor
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\newcommand{\mysize}{3cm}
\newcommand{\connectlength}{0.6cm}

\tikzstyle{nodestyle}=[draw, minimum size=\mysize,
label={[anchor = east]25:$\text{A}$},
label={[anchor = east]-25:$\text{B}$},]

\begin{document}

    \begin{circuitikz}

    \node[nodestyle] (node) {node1};
    \path (node.north) ++(-2cm,1cm) node[vcc]  (nodevcc) {VCC};% \draw will work also
    \node[vcc] at ($(node.north)+(2cm,1cm)$) {calc};
    \node[vcc,yshift=1cm] at (node.north) {yshift};

    \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]